# Internet explorer Div alignment issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code works fine on chrome and firefox but in I.E (latest version) , "px" thing is shown in next line. I tried display:inline , that does the trick but disturbs the alignment badly. Is their any other way by which i can make them align on same line ? Thanks

```
<div class="dfs_config_group">
    <div class="dfs_config_field_label">Font Size</div>
    <div class="dfs_config_field">
        <div class="dfs_config_append mini">
            <input type="text" name="dg_footer_wrapper_inner[font-size]" value="12">
            <div class="add_on">px</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the full code (HTML and CSS) required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You may want to avoid IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used style="display:inline" and my issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using display:inline-block